# Screen Glitch After Sleep [Desktop]

Tags: release-hera, suspend

I have an interesting problem with my desktop installation of elementary OS (5.1 Hera).

Whenever I wake my system from sleep my entire screen is a mess of digital noise. Otherwise, I do not experience any screen tearing. I have not been able to find this problem posted anywhere else. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I need to share specific system information.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have the same problem with MacBook Pro 15 pouce Mi-2010, and you ?

Comment: For the googlers, I'm having the same problem with an MSI GS66.  ElementaryOS 5.1.7 Hera.  Freshly installed today.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, I did not solve the problem. I have since moved my desktop to Pop_OS which hasn't presented this issue to me. It's worth noting that I also have the issue on my 2013 MacBook Air which still runs Elementary OS.